# What does "average revenue growth" over multiple periods of time mean?

Tags: calculation, value-averaging

In particular, given 10 years of revenue data, what is "average revenue growth" understood to mean?

1. The arithmetic average of the 9 yearly growth rates
2. The [geometric rate of return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Geometric_average_rate_of_return)
3. Something else
4. No clear meaning -- phrase is not specific enough

I have to update an infographic for a lay audience which includes the "ten-year average revenue growth". The old report used arithmetic average, but geometric rate of return feels right to me. The difference is small, though, in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, I believe it means arithmetic average, but I agree with you that geometric rate of return would let you find the 10 yr number given the first, where the arithmetic won't.